# Refresh dialog in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am building an application where it is necessary to register a user, more precisely a picture for a user besides his name, username and some other information, when the registration window is show, a default user image is load, then when they select a new image the default image dissapear and the selected one is displayed on the window, and a new button is displayed as well, this button allows the user to remove the selected picture, so the default image must be display again, but I still can't display again the default picture in case de button is clicked to return to the default picture and remove the selected one

View where users are listed and the modal window is displayed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
         <ui:composition template="/sesionAdmin/_admintmp.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="body">
    <h:head>
        <h:outputScript library="js" name ="Calendario.js"/>
    </h:head>  
    <h:body>

        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton id="createButton"  value="Registrar usuario" 
                             onclick="PF('UsuarioCreateDialog').show()">

            </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>
        <p:separator/>
        <h:form id="UsuarioListForm">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="panelgrid">
                <p:outputLabel style="font-weight: bold;" value="Buscar usuario:" />
                        <p:inputText  placeholder="Digite nombres, apellidos, nombre de usuario o email" 
                                      style="width: 350px;"  value="#{usuarioController.datoBusqueda}" >
                            <p:ajax event="keyup" update="datalist" listener="#{usuarioController.buscarUsuario()}" />                                
                        </p:inputText>                          
                    </p:panelGrid>
            <p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{usuarioController.items}" var="item"
                         paginator="true" widgetVar="tablaUsuarios"
                         rows="10"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20"
                         >
                <f:facet name="header">

                </f:facet>

                <p:column >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Nombres"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.usunombres}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Apellidos"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.usuapellidos}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Nombre  de usuario"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.usunombreusuario}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Email"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.usuemail}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Cargo"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.carid.carnombre}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column width="70" style="text-align: center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Foto" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:graphicImage id="imgUsuario" value="#{usuarioController.imagenFlujo}" width="50"  height="50" >
                        <f:param name="id" value="#{item.usuid}" />
                    </p:graphicImage>                            

                </p:column> 
                <p:column style="width: 90px">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Acciones"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:commandButton id="viewButton" icon="ui-icon-search" action="#{usuarioController.seleccionarUsuarioVer(item)}" update=":UsuarioViewForm, :formfotoView" oncomplete="PF('UsuarioViewDialog').show()" />
                    <p:commandButton id="editButton" icon="ui-icon-pencil" action="#{usuarioController.seleccionarUsuarioEditar(item)}"  update=":UsuarioEditForm, :formEditarfoto" oncomplete="PF('UsuarioEditDialog').show()" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>

        <ui:include src="RegistrarUsuario.xhtml"/>
        <ui:include src="EditarUsuario.xhtml"/>
        <ui:include src="VerInfoUsuario.xhtml"/>
        <p:dialog header="Información" modal="true" position="center" widgetVar="mensajeRegistroExitoso" closable="false">
            <p:messages  style="font-size: 15px;"  showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton  value="Aceptar" style="font-weight: normal;"
                                  onclick="PF('mensajeRegistroExitoso').hide()"/>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:body>
        </ui:define>
         </ui:composition>
</html>
```

User dialog window

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">



    <ui:composition>            
        <p:dialog id="UsuarioCreateDlg" widgetVar="UsuarioCreateDialog" modal="true" resizable="false" 
                  appendTo="@(body)" header="Registrar usuario">
            <h:outputStylesheet name="css/appearUploadFile.css" />
            <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{usuarioController.cancelarRegistroUsuario()}"/>
            <p:outputLabel style="float: right;" value="&ensp; Campos obligatorios" />  
            <p:outputLabel  style="float: right; font-style: italic; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; color: red;"  value="* " />                      
            <br/>
            <!--h:form id="formfoto" enctype="multipart/form-data"-->
                <center>
                    <p:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Foto de perfil" />                   
                </center>
                <center>    
                    <br/>
                    <p:graphicImage  rendered="#{usuarioController.miImagen ==null}"
                                     style="height:100px; width:100px;"
                                     value="#{usuarioController.imagenDefecto}"/>
                    <p:graphicImage  rendered="#{usuarioController.miImagen !=null}"
                                     id="img"
                                     style="height:100px; width:100px;"
                                     value="#{usuarioController.miImagen}"
                                     cache="false"/>
                    <p:fileUpload  mode="advanced" auto="true" fileUploadListener="#{usuarioController.convertirImagenABytes}"
                                   allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpe?g|png)$/" sizeLimit="10000000" invalidFileMessage="El archivo no está en el formato válido"
                                   required="true"
                                   update="@form" multiple="false" label="Subir imagen">
                    </p:fileUpload> 
                    <h:commandLink rendered="#{usuarioController.miImagen !=null}" 
                                     value="Imagen por defecto" 
                                     actionListener="#{usuarioController.establecerFotoPorDefecto()}"

                                     >
                        <f:ajax execute="@all" render="@form"/>
                        <p:ajax update="UsuarioCreateDlg"/>
                    </h:commandLink>

                </center>
                <br/>
            <!--/h:form-->
            <h:form id="UsuarioCreateForm">
                <p:panelGrid  styleClass="panelgrid"  id="panel2">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Nombres:" />
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-style: italic; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; color: red;"  value="* " />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="usunombres" value="#{usuarioController.selected.usunombres}"
                                         title="#{bundleAdmin.CreateUsuarioTitle_usunombres}" required="true" 
                                         requiredMessage="Campo obligatorio">
                                <f:validator validatorId="ValidarCampo75Caracteres"/>
                                <p:ajax event="keyup" update="msgCaracteresNombre"/>
                            </p:inputText>

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Apellidos:" />
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-style: italic; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; color: red;"  value="* " />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="usuapellidos" value="#{usuarioController.selected.usuapellidos}"
                                         title="#{bundleAdmin.CreateUsuarioTitle_usuapellidos}" required="true" 
                                         requiredMessage="Campo obligatorio">
                                <f:validator validatorId="ValidarCampo75Caracteres"/>
                                <p:ajax event="keyup" update="msgCaracteresApellido"/>
                            </p:inputText>                                        
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row> 
                        <p:column>

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:message id="msgCaracteresNombre" for="usunombres"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:message id="msgCaracteresApellido" for="usuapellidos"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>

                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Genero:"  />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneRadio value="#{usuarioController.selected.usugenero}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Masculino" itemValue="M" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Femenino" itemValue="F" />                                    
                            </p:selectOneRadio>

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Fecha de nacimiento:" />
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-style: italic; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; color: red;"  value="* " />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:calendar id="usufechanacimiento" 
                                        placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" 
                                        value="#{usuarioController.selected.usufechanacimiento}" 
                                        title="#{bundleAdmin.EditUsuarioTitle_usufechanacimiento}" 
                                        required="true" 
                                        readonlyInput="true"
                                        requiredMessage="Campo obligatorio" 
                                        showOn="button"
                                        navigator = "true"
                                        locale="es"
                                        maxdate="#{usuarioController.fechaHoy}">
                                <p:ajax event="keyup" update="msgUsuFechaNacimiento"/>
                                <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="msgUsuFechaNacimiento"/>   </p:calendar>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:row>
                    <p:row> 
                        <p:column>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:message id="msgUsuFechaNacimiento" for="usufechanacimiento"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Email:" />
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-style: italic; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; color: red;"  value="* " />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="usuemail" value="#{usuarioController.selected.usuemail}"
                                         title="#{bundleAdmin.CreateUsuarioTitle_usuemail}" 
                                         required="true" requiredMessage="Campo obligatorio">
                                <f:validator validatorId="ValidarCampoCorreoElectronico"/>
                                <p:ajax event="keyup" update="msgCaracteresEMail"/>
                            </p:inputText>

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Cargo:" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="carid" value="#{usuarioController.cargo}" >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{cargoController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                                               var="caridItem"
                                               itemValue="#{caridItem}"
                                               itemLabel="#{caridItem.carnombre}"
                                               />
                                <f:validator validatorId="ValidarCamposSeleccionar"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:row>
                    <p:row> 
                        <p:column>

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:message id="msgCaracteresEMail" for="usuemail"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:message for="carid"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Tipo de usuario:" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="grupoId" value="#{usuarioController.grupo.gruid}" >
                                <p:ajax event="change" update="grupoId"/> 
                                <f:selectItems value="#{grupoController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                                               var="grupo"
                                               itemValue="#{grupo.gruid}"
                                               itemLabel="#{grupo.grudescripcion}"
                                               >

                                </f:selectItems>
                                <f:validator validatorId="ValidarCamposSeleccionar"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:row>
                    <p:row> 
                        <p:column>

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:message  for="grupoId"/>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:row>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Nombre de usuario:" />
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-style: italic; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; color: red;"  value="* " />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="usunombreusuario" value="#{usuarioController.selected.usunombreusuario}" 
                                         title="#{bundleAdmin.CreateUsuarioTitle_usunombreusuario}" required="true" 
                                         requiredMessage="Campo obligatorio">
                                <f:validator validatorId="ValidarCampoNombreUsuario"/>
                                <p:ajax event="keyup" update="msgCaracteresNombreUsuario"/>

                            </p:inputText>


                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;" value="Contraseña:" />
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-style: italic; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; color: red;"  value="* " />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:password id="usucontrasena" value="#{usuarioController.selected.usucontrasena}"
                                        title="#{bundleAdmin.CreateUsuarioTitle_usucontrasena}" 
                                        required="true" requiredMessage="Campo obligatorio"/>        
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                    <p:row> 
                        <p:column>

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:message id="msgCaracteresNombreUsuario" for="usunombreusuario"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:message for="usucontrasena"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:separator/>
                <center>
                    <p:commandButton action="#{usuarioController.registrarUsuario()}"
                                     value="Registrar" update=":UsuarioListForm:datalist, panel2" 

                                     />
                </center>

            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </ui:composition>

</html>
```

User controller

```
public class UsuarioController implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private com.unicauca.coordinacionpis.sessionbean.UsuarioFacade ejbUsuario;
    @EJB
    private UsuariogrupoFacade ejbUsuarioGrupo;

    private List<Usuario> items = null;
    private Cargo cargo;
    private Grupo grupo;
    private List<Usuario> filtroBusqueda;

    private boolean campoFoto;
    private boolean campoContrasena;

    private String contrasena;
    private String datoBusqueda;

    private Usuario usuario;
    private UploadedFile file;

    private SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha;


    private byte[] imagen;
    private DefaultStreamedContent miImagen;
    private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

    public StreamedContent getImagenDefecto(){
        return Utilidades.getImagenPorDefecto("foto");
    }
    public StreamedContent getImagen(Usuario usuario) {
        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        String id = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("idUsu");
        if (usuario.getUsufoto() == null) {
            return Utilidades.getImagenPorDefecto("foto");
        } else {
            return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(usuario.getUsufoto()));
        }

    }
    public void establecerFotoPorDefecto()
    {
        System.out.println("Hallo");
        this.miImagen = null;
        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        //requestContext.execute("PF('UsuarioCreateDialog').hide()");
        //requestContext.execute("PF('UsuarioCreateDialog').show()");
        //this.imagenPorDefecto();
    }
public DefaultStreamedContent getMiImagen() {
    convertirBytesAImagen();
    /*if(miImagen==null)
        miImagen = Utilidades.getImagenPorDefecto("foto");*/
    return miImagen;
}
public void convertirBytesAImagen()
{
    if(imagen != null)
    {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) imagen);
        miImagen = new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "image/png");
    }
}
```

}

The method I am calling to set the default picture is establecerFotoPorDefecto()

Comment: That's way too much code to read. Please cut it down to the parts which are really necessary to reproduce the problem. Create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @lastresort: if you type [ mcve ] without the spaces, you automatically get [mcve]